# padding-top causes bottom of scrollbar to disappear in FF

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, padding

I have the following DIV configured in my HTML page:

```
<div id="contentDiv" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 20px; overflow: auto; height: 100%;" >
```

The content is large enough that a vertical scrollbar is required.
In IE, the page looks fine.  However, in FF, the bottom of the scrollbar overflows off the bottom of the page by the amount the padding-top is set (i.e. 20px).  Is there a way to keep the padding-top and have the full scrollbar display in FF?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If IE versions lower than 8 do not matter, you can use [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing) to include padding in block dimensions.